# Update table of a database from an excel sheet (.csv) which is uploaded in ASP

Tags: ajax, asp-classic

I want to make an asp page where the user will upload a csv file which will be displayed dynamically, giving the user two options - to accept or reject the displayed table. If the user clicks on accept, the excel (csv) file should be updated to the database directly.

I have already done the following things:

1. the csv file is uploaded successfully and the table is displayed dynamically.
2. reject button, which will reject the uploaded file and refresh the page.

I need your help to achieve this:

Use an ajax script in a function called update() which will use the xmlhttp object to link all the parameters (columns of the table) and pass it on to a asp file which contains the code to update the database.

I hope you get the idea. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you search for simular posts?

Comment: yes but I couldnt find any relevant post ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery Ajax functions to achieve your desired effect. You can also write your on ajax functions in pure javascript.

You can find details about it: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/